# Keras: Multiply with constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is it possible `x*a` from input `size(None, None, 3)` in Keras? For example, the input `x` and `constant a: x(batch,None,None,1024)*a(batch,1)`.

I use input `size (64, 64, 3)` in train but test data should use variable input sizes. The test size can not be adjusted for fair image processing.

I try Lambda `function(lambda x : x * a)(seq)`. Then, I got no problem in code. And then, I start model.fit function, I got error:

```
------------->>tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [7,4,4,1024] vs. [7,1].
```

.

```
conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)

conv_c = Conv2D(num_classes, 1, activation='softmax')(conv5)
conv_c1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="class_output")(conv_c)

conv_c1_1 = conv_c1[:, 0:1]
conv_c1_2 = conv_c1[:, 1:2]
conv_c1_3 = conv_c1[:, 2:3]

conv5_b = Lambda(lambda x: x * conv_c1_1)(conv5) #conv5:Tensor(shape=(?, 4, 4, 1024))
conv5_h = Lambda(lambda x: x * conv_c1_2)(conv5) #conv_c1_1: Tensor(shape=(?, 1))
conv5_r = Lambda(lambda x: x * conv_c1_3)(conv5)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this exactly what you want, but you could use implicit broadcasting as follows: `Lambda(lambda x: x * a[:, None, None, None])`